# How to update the row with the most recent timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

Let's say I have a row with fields `a,b,c, d & time_stamp`, where `a` is the unique key and `d` represents a "deleted" row (which I don't actually delete, as I want to keep it for an audit trail).

If I modify the row I won't just UPDATE, becuase I want to keep that audit trail. Instead I will mark the most receent row as being deleted and then insert a new row (I hope Ihave described that clearly).

Now, (how) can I with one SQL staement UPDATE the most recent row (by time_stamp) where a= ?

Maybe something like

```
UPDATE <table>  
  SET d="Y"
  WHERE a=<some value> AND time_stamp=MAX(time_stamp)
```

is that correct? Could it be done better? Thanks for any help

Comment: you said `a` is the unique key so you can use it alone in `where` clause

Comment: +1 for the comment. I just rememebred it is no longer uniue. It used to be, but f to add auti trail I am no longer deleting rows, just marking the "deleted" field as "Y", than adding a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TestTable
SET D= Y
FROM (
      SELECT MAX(Time_Stamp) as MaxTimeStamp
      FROM TestTable
      WHERE A=x
     ) t
WHERE t.Time_Stamp = TestTable.MaxTimeStamp
```

Just make sure your timestamps are precise enough for the level of activity on the table that there are no 2 rows with the same A and time_stamp values. If you have > 1 row with the same timestamp and A value then you may update more than just the most recent row.

Comment: +1 thanks; I finally struggled my through it and it is coorect. As first to reply, you get awarded the answer

Comment: Btw, at the momemnt a 1 second resolution seems to be ok as databse contents are created by human inervention via broowser. For more accuracy on future projects I guess I could use an auto-incerment field, posibly combined with the tiemstamp?

Comment: You could create an auto-increment identity column which would be accurate. In MSSQL this can be done fairly easily, though I am unsure of the equivalent in MySQL so I have left it out of my answer. Same thing with the timestamp data type in MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
UPDATE MyTable T
SET T.d="Y"
WHERE T.a=<some value> AND 
T.time_stamp=(SELECT MAX(T2.time_stamp) FROM MyTable T2 WHERE T2.a = T.a)
```

IF `a` is unique and/or the PK then it could be done easier/better:

```
UPDATE MyTable T
SET T.d="Y"
WHERE T.a=<some value>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks very much. Your first solution seems like @wt_w's, just wrtten differently. Correct? I am afraid that A can't be unique. Nothig can (except he most recent row for each A where d shoudl not be Y) because I want that audit trail. Hmm, think I'll ask a question about audit trails. Thanks again